# How to match string in between nth occurrence of whitespace and nth occurrence of comma?

Tags: sql, regex

I am editing in PL/SQL.

I have the following string

*59 W Grand Ave Chicago, IL 60654*

I need to match the string 'Chicago', and I can do that by matching everything in between the fourth space character, and the first comma character.  So far I have come up with:

```
(?<=\s)(.*)(?=,)
```

However, even though that matches everything up to the comma, it starts from the first space character.  How can I start the match from the 4th space character instead?

I have tried `(?<=\s){4}(.*)(?=,)` but then it doesn't match anything.

Comment: What environment are you implementing this regex in?

Comment: I am editing in PL/SQL

Comment: Depending on the environment you are using this on, just use the `/\S+,/U` ensuring that you do not use the `g` flag. This will only capture the word before the first comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression would be slightly complicated. Let's maybe try another approach and maybe focus on the two letter State and swipe back to the word before which, using an expression similar to:

```
^.+?(\w+)[,\s]+?[A-Z]{2}.+$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/dvOnHO/1/)

We can see that we would face problem if the City has more than one word. If, however, we would have a list of fixed words such as `Ave`, `BLVD`, `ST` right before the city, we could most likely come up with a better expression, such as:

```
^.+Ave\s+(.+?)[,\s]+?[A-Z]{2}.+$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/HwSUW5/1/)

which we would expand it to:

```
^.+(Ave|Street|ST|BLVD)\s+(.+?)[,\s]+?[A-Z]{2}.+$
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/azDMul/1/)

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^.+Ave\s+(.+?)[,\s]+?[A-Z]{2}.+$/gm;
const str = `59 W Grand Ave Chicago, IL 60654
59 E Grand Hotel Ave Chicago IL 60654
59 E George Washington Ave New York, NY 60654
59 E George Washington Ave San Diego CA 60654
59 E George Washington Ave St. Petersburg, CA 60654`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Emma, I appreciate learning about this approach.  One thing I notice, when I regex on regular expressions 101, it seems to only highlight Chicago in "Group 1", but not the full match.  Is there a practical distinction?